# Pulling Data based on optional parameter in Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angular directive that displays a list of permits.  This directive will be used in two places: A Vehicle screen and a Permits screen.

On the vehicle screen it will show permits for that specific vehicle.  On the permits screen it will show all permits.

To accomplish this I was going to use an attribute vehicle in the directive.  The issue I am facing is that I want to pull the data based on whether the vehicle attribute has been supplied and if so pull based on the vehicle value.

Here is a snippet of what I have and it is working when the vehicle attribute is supplied but how do I make it work in the case when it isnt?

```
angular.module("app").directive('etVehiclePermits', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "app/vehicles/permits/etVehiclePermits.html",
        scope: {
            vehicle: '@'
        },
    controller: function ($scope, $attrs, dataService) {
        $attrs.$observe('vehicle', function (value) {
            if (value != '') {
                dataService.getPermits(value).then(function (data) {
                    $scope.permits = data;
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends on how your `dataService.getPermits` works. If it's a simple case of it getting only permits for a vehicle when that parameter is used and getting all permits otherwise then you could do something like the code below (value being undefined when no vehicle is supplied).

```
$attrs.$observe('vehicle', function (value) {
       dataService.getPermits(value).then(function (data) {
                $scope.permits = data;
            });
        }
    });
```